# How to know sqlplus version from inside sqlplus

Tags: sqlplus

I am offered (by some framework) to run commands in sqlplus, but am not launching it myself.
I'd like to know the version of that sqlplus running.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Within SQL*Plus, there are some preDEFINEd substitution variable:

```
SQL> define
DEFINE _DATE           = "23-NOV-13" (CHAR)
DEFINE _CONNECT_IDENTIFIER = "" (CHAR)
DEFINE _USER           = "" (CHAR)
DEFINE _PRIVILEGE      = "" (CHAR)
DEFINE _SQLPLUS_RELEASE = "1102000100" (CHAR)
DEFINE _EDITOR         = "Notepad" (CHAR)
```

Notice the _SQLPLUS_RELEASE. You reference this in SQLPLUS.

For example, you can do something like:

```
sqlplus -S /nolog<<EOF
prompt &_SQLPLUS_RELEASE
quit
EOF
```

Comment: This solution is nice because it does not require you to login.  To make it work on Window, I just created a second file with the 2 commands and used:
sqlplus -S /nolog < sqlplus_rel.txt

Answer (score 1):

You can just use command :

```
sqlplus -V
```

And you should get :

```
SQL*Plus: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 18.3.0.0.0
```

Or :

```
SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.12.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can with an actual query. You *may* be able to get it with this:

```
SELECT
  PROGRAM, MODULE
from    v$session s
order by s.sid;
```

The Module column may contain the version number, it might not. It depends on the program. If memory serves correctly, sqlplus does not give this. For example, TOAD gives "TOAD Freeware 11.0.0.116"

Comment: The problem with that idea, is that I am far from the only user connected on that database, so finding my sessions would be difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just connect to sqlplus through commande line. In LINUX you can do the following:

```
[orafresh@ljsrv1123 ~]$ sqlplus / as sysdba
```

Which will return:

> SQL*Plus: Release 11.1.0.7.0 - Production on Fri Jul 14 12:47:36 2017
>
> Copyright (c) 1982, 2008, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
>
> Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release
>   11.1.0.7.0 - 64bit Production With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

Answer (score 0):

```sql
> select &_sqlplus_release from dual;
old   1: select &_sqlplus_release from dual
new   1: select 1803000000 from dual

1803000000
----------
1803000000
```